# How to unit test stream generators

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, generator

I am setting up unit tests for my flask app. A lot of my functions streams the output to the gui like this one:

```
def stream():
    def generate():
        if request.method == "POST":
            hostname = request.data.decode('utf-8')
            hostname_dn = "{}.{}".format(hostname, DOMAIN)

            logging.info("Connecting to: {}".format(hostname_dn))

            # Connect to hostname and execute create reports
            client = set_up_client()
            client.connect(hostname_dn,
                           username=USERNAME,
                           password=PASSWORD)

            cmd = ('tail -f -n0 /home/server.log')

            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)

            for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""):
                logging.info(line, end="")
                yield line
                if re.search(r'keyword', line):
                    yield 'keyword detected\n'
                    break

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/html')
```

My question is how could I use `assert` statements to verify these functions? Since they return a stream response. Is there a way I can slap on an extra parameter in the return statement like 200 or something then use assert to verify the stream was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should test how the `stream` func works. So I'd recommend to isolate (mock) everything that is not related to it and test how it behaves. So mock a `Response` object and iterate over a generator:

```
@patch("Response")
def test_stream(self, response_mock):
    # this should return invoked Response mock, 
    # so you need to retrieve a first argument
    res = stream()
    args, _ = res.call_args
    stream_gen = args[0]
    n_runs = 0
    for i in stream_gen:
        self.assertEqual(i, expected_value)
        n_runs += 1
    self.assertEqual(n_runs, expected_runs_count)
```